# Why is my code for finding number of sets in a binary not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

```
count=0
n=int(input())
while(n!=0):
    if n&1>0:
        count+=1
       
    n = n >> 1
print(count)
```

I want to find number of set bits in a binary but my code doesn't seem to work . Why?

Comment: Can you please give an input for which your code fails?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code.

Comment: for example my input is 1011 and i want the input as 3 as it has 3 set bits.But it shows 8 ......what I want is that I want my program to read 1011 as a binary number cause in the program when i use the rightshift operator it converts my 1011 to its binary 001111110011 which gives 8 which makes sense cause it has 8 bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my input is 1011 and i want the input as 3 as it has 3 set bits.But it shows 8

This is because the function `int(...)` interprets the input string `1011` as a decimal number. 1011<sub>dec</sub> = 1111110011<sub>bin</sub> therefore the answer *"8 bits are set"* is correct.

If you want to enter binary numbers instead of decimal numbers, then you could specify the base using `int(input(), base=2)`. However, in this case it would be far easier to directly count the `1` characters in the input string instead of converting that string into a number and then counting the set bits in that number. To do so, replace your whole script by

```
input().count("1")
```